# Abstract with amsart class and fontspec (with XeLaTeX)

Tags: xetex, fontspec, amsart

There is an error message which I do not understand when I use `amsart` in conjunction with `fontspec`. The math text in the abstract seems to be deemed too small?

The error is

> \textfont 6 is undefined (character =).

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\title{T}\author{A}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
$a=b$
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but loading `mathspec` before `fontspec` will solve it.

Comment: @AlanMunn very clever! I'm happy with that so far, thanks!

Comment: For some unknown (to me) reason, the mathcode of `=` changes in the `abstract` environment; with ``\begin{abstract}\mathcode`="303D`` the example compiles.

Comment: @egreg Interesting... The parenthesis are also problematic, for instance $f(x)$ in the abstract generates the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the compatibility of `fontspec` with the AMS classes. The problem happens when a font size changing command such as `\Small` is issued (such a command is defined by `amsart` and `amsbook` to change font size relative to the current font size).

Apparently, the `legacymaths` symbol font doesn't get defined, and this upsets `amsart` or, more precisely, the font size changing commands.

The solution is to call

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
```

(which is done by `mathspec`, so Alan Munn's advice works) or to define the required symbol font:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\DeclareSymbolFont{legacymaths}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{legacymaths}{bold}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
```

Comment: What is the relation between `mathspec` and `fontspec`?

Comment: @Alexey `mathspec` is built over `fontspec` and aims to use text fonts also for math; the results are rather good, but not for extensive math usage.

Comment: I see, thanks. If i understand correctly, `fontspec` is strongly recommended in XeLaTeX, so is it safe to use `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`?

Comment: @Alexey The `no-math` option basically doesn't change the font used for family 0 (upright math letters).